# How can I connect to bitcoin-qt client with public ip address

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, json-rpc

I used the bitcoin client but i want to connect to it using public ip adress not localhost.

From that machine i could reach bitcoin using localhost but when I am using public ip address with the ports required it is not working.

- Firewall is down on that machine.

I added this line to bitcoin.conf

- allowrpc=mypublicaddress

Also my debug window I see these two lines

- 2014-06-05 15:04:43 AddLocal(mylocalAddress:18333,1)
- 2014-06-05 15:04:44 AddLocal(myPublicAdress:18333,4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forward the port if you're in a LAN.

You need to add the IP of the server who is making the JSON-RPC call to the bitcoin.config file such as below:

```
rpcallowip= IPMakingTheRequest
```